# Updating NSDateFormatter with NSTimer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have created a custom class which show time date formatter and I need a timer like  method to update the seconds, so here is my code :

CustomClass.m

```
- (NSString *) showLocaleTime {

            NSDateFormatter *timeFormater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
timeFormater = [setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss "];

NSString *currDay = [timeFormater stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
currDay = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",currDay];
[timeFormater release];


    return timer;
}


- (void) updateLocaleTime {

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(showLocaleTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
```

viewController.m :

```
CustomClass *time = [[CustomClass alloc]init];
label.text = [time showLocaleTime];

[time updateLocaleTime];
```

But the problem is the `updateLocaleTime` does not call to update seconds ! am I missing something ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `updateLocaleTime` in `CustomClass`, just start the timer in the view controller itself.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(updateLocaleTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Add `updateLocaleTime` method to the `viewController`

```
- (void) updateLocaleTime {

   CustomClass *time = [[CustomClass alloc]init];
   label.text = [time showLocaleTime];
   [time release];
}
```

But here we are allocating and releasing the `CustomClass` again and again for every 0.5 seconds. Instead you declare it as class member, in .h file and allocate that in `viewDidLoad`.

So no need to allocate in `updateLocaleTime` method. Also release that `time` in `viewDidUnload` method.

Comment: is there any way to call this method as I said ? :-s I need it like that, Its public API for my friends I need it be very simple

Comment: As Einstein said, everything should be made as simple as possible, but no simpler.

Comment: Thanks , but I received `SIGABRT` !!?

Comment: SORRY my code was wrong ! and I edited again would you please reconsider again ?

Answer (score 0):

Where do you update the label text, after computing the new time?  (You compute then new time but the it falls on the floor.)

Eg, add `label.text = timer;` to your showLocalTime method, and skip returning `timer`.

Comment: You may need to do a `setNeedsDisplay` after updating the text value.

Comment: If I skip the return , `compiler show warning as : Control reaches end of non-void function`

Comment: (But you have bigger problems.  You need to rethink what you're doing from the top.)

Comment: SORRY  my code was wrong ! and I edited again would you please reconsider again ?

Comment: I'm afraid you didn't improve it noticeably.  I'd suggest you start from scratch and think carefully about what happens when.  Remember, Objective-C is an [imperative programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming).